# Java: Split String around "+"

Tags: java, regex, string, split, nullpointerexception

Just found out, that I get a `NullPointerException` when trying to split a String around `+`, but if I split around `-` or anything else (and change the String as well of course), it works just fine.

```
String string = "Strg+Q";
String[] parts = string.split("+");
String part1 = parts[0]; //Strg
String part2 = parts[1]; //Q
```

Would love to hear from you guys, what I am doing wrong!

This one works:

```
String string = "Strg-Q";
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0]; //Strg
String part2 = parts[1]; //Q
```

Comment: **Why** does `+` make, specifically, a NPE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
final String string = "Strg+Q";
final String[] parts = string.split("\\+");
System.out.println(parts[0]); // Strg
System.out.println(parts[1]); // Q
```

Comment: Downvoted because you've wrapped Java code in a Javascript code snippet. That's wrong

Answer (score 4):

As `+` is one of the special `regex` syntaxes you need to `escape` it.
Use

```
String[] parts = string.split("\\+");
```

Instead of

```
String[] parts = string.split("+");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
silly mistake from me :-)

Comment: @Bambi Happy to help you!!!

Answer (score 3):

It happens because `+` is a special character in Regex - it's the match-one-or-more quantifier.

The only thing you need to do is to escape it:

```
String[] parts = string.split("\\+");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
silly mistake from me :-)

Answer (score 3):

String.split(...) expects a Regular Expression and the '+' is a special character. Try:

```
 String string = "Strg+Q";
 String[] parts = string.split("[+]");
 String part1 = parts[0]; //Strg
 String part2 = parts[1]; //Q
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, '+' is special when dealing with regex. In general, if a character is special you can use `Pattern.quote()` to escape it, as well as `"\\+"`. Documentation on Pattern: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Example:

```
String string = "Strg-Q";
String[] parts = string.split(Pattern.quote("+"));
String part1 = parts[0]; //Strg
String part2 = parts[1]; //Qenter code here
```

Remember to import pattern from `java.util.regex`!

Answer (score 2):

`+` is a special regex character which means that you need to escape it in order to use it as a normal character.

```
 String[] parts = string.split("\\+");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
silly mistake from me :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you got here is that `"+"` is a meta character in Java, so you need to "scape" it by using `"\\+"`.

Answer (score 1):

Amit beat me too it. string.split() takes a regular expression as its argument. In regexes + is a special symbol. Escape it with a backslash. Then, since it's a java string, escape the backslash with another backslash, so you get \+. Try testing your regular expressions on an online regex tester.